# Android: reset the scroll position to top when new data is loaded in listview

Tags: android, listview

I am learning Android and trying to implement pagination (or infinite scroll) for the ListView of records.

I am using the setOnScrollListener of the ListView to read when the list is scrolled down and records end so I can do an API call to my server and get next set of data.

I am still trying to figure out how to read the end of data when the list is scrolled all the way down and all the way up (so next/previous set of data can be fetched)

```
accountList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
     @Override
     public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
           Log.i("SCROLL", "-----firstVisibleItem: " + firstVisibleItem + " | visibleItemCount: " + visibleItemCount + " | totalItemCount: " + totalItemCount + " | pageIndex: " + pageIndex);

           if((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) && totalItemCount > 0) {
              Log.i("SCROLL", "-------- we have reached at the bottom of the scroll list");
              pageIndex = pageIndex + pageSize;
              getAllAccountsRecords();
           } else if(firstVisibleItem == 0 && visibleItemCount > 0 && totalItemCount > 0 && pageIndex > 0) {
              Log.i("SCROLL", "-------- we have reached at the top of the scroll list");
              pageIndex = pageIndex - pageSize;
              if(pageIndex >= 0) {
                getAllAccountsRecords();
              }
           }
     }
 });
```

The getAllAccountsRecords calls AsyncTask and does the API call to repopulate the listview.

```
public void getAllAccountsRecords() {
        new GetAccounts().execute();
    }
```

However whenever I scroll all the way down to the initial dataset, it goes into a frantic loop and starts incrementing the pageIndex value from 0 > 10 > 20 > 30 > 40...so on

Below is the debug log

```
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 3 | visibleItemCount: 5 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 0
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 3 | visibleItemCount: 5 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 0
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 3 | visibleItemCount: 5 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 0
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 3 | visibleItemCount: 6 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 0
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 3 | visibleItemCount: 6 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 0
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 3 | visibleItemCount: 6 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 0
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 4 | visibleItemCount: 6 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 0
I: -------- we have reached at the bottom of the scroll list
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 4 | visibleItemCount: 6 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 10
I: -------- we have reached at the bottom of the scroll list
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 4 | visibleItemCount: 6 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 20
I: -------- we have reached at the bottom of the scroll list
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 4 | visibleItemCount: 6 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 30
I: -------- we have reached at the bottom of the scroll list
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 0 | visibleItemCount: 6 | totalItemCount: 10 | pageIndex: 40
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 0 | visibleItemCount: 0 | totalItemCount: 0 | pageIndex: 40
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 0 | visibleItemCount: 0 | totalItemCount: 0 | pageIndex: 40
I: -----firstVisibleItem: 0 | visibleItemCount: 0 | totalItemCount: 0 | pageIndex: 40
```

So it never initializes the firstVisibleItem to 0 hence the pageIndex keeps getting incremented.

**I have looked at many infinite scroll solutions but they all fetch data from a static source and it is not working for me, so I had to come up with my own**

Any help in solving this or making it better is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For clarification: You open the view and load the first 10 items. Then as you scroll down, you load items 11-20, 21-30, etc. As you scroll up, you want to load those items again. So if you are on items 31-40 and scroll up, you then want to load 21-30, 11-20, and then items 1-10 again. Is this correct?

Comment: Ideally that is how it should be but what I am afraid is that if I am scrolling down and is at item 8, then what if the onScroll kicks in and refreshes the list with 11-20, where the user (maybe) just wanted to scroll till 10 and click the 9th record to open it. I want them to go all the way down, reach the end, then just do a finger swipe to kick in the process to get next records.

Comment: Are you replacing items 1-10 with items 11-20 when they are loaded or are you appending items 11-20 below items 1-10?

Comment: I am replacing them.

Comment: Do you need to replace them?. You can add them to the underlying ArrayAdapter for you ListView and then call .notifyDataSetChanged(). This will update the ListView so that elements 11-20 are appended after 1-10 and the User can keep scrolling or stop when they want to select element 8 (as in your given case)